# File download -Returns blank file when download a excel file from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
 public ActionResult ExportLeadTimingReport(JLRReportSearchCriteriaViewModel searchCriteria)
    {
        OperationResponse<DataTable> LeadTimingReport = new OperationResponse<DataTable>();
        LeadTimingReport.Value = new DataTable();
          byte[] file = LeadManager.GetJLRLeadTimingReportForExport(searchCriteria);

                HttpContext.Response.ClearContent();
                HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                HttpContext.Response.Buffer = true;
                HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Export.xlsx");
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
                HttpContext.Response.Charset = "";

                HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(file);
                HttpContext.Response.End();

                return null;
    }
```

Returns empty excel file. But binary array contains data, but when its called it gives blank excel file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please modify the code as given below

```
public ActionResult ExportLeadTimingReport(JLRReportSearchCriteriaViewModel searchCriteria)
    {
       OperationResponse<DataTable> LeadTimingReport = new OperationResponse<DataTable>();
       LeadTimingReport.Value = new DataTable();
       byte[] file = LeadManager.GetJLRLeadTimingReportForExport(searchCriteria);

       this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
       return File(file , "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Comment: but it shows this error "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent."

Comment: Can you try any of the solution mentioned here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383169/server-cannot-set-status-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-iis7-5