# C# Google OAUTH2 using OWIN on Mono results in "System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): headers have already been sent"

Tags: c#, authentication, model-view-controller, mono, owin

I've followed a number of tutorials for adding google OAUTH2 authentication to an existing MVC project, but I end up with the same issue involving a 404 to the client and the following trace generated:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): headers have already been sent
  at System.Web.HttpResponse.set_StatusCode (System.Int32 value) [0x00012] in <d31574f4ab6745f49b1626160268508f>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.set_StatusCode (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <d31574f4ab6745f49b1626160268508f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary.IPropertySource.SetResponseStatusCode (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary.set_ResponseStatusCode (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary.PropertiesTrySetValue (System.String key, System.Object value) [0x00257] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary.System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<System.String,System.Object>.set_Item (System.String key, System.Object value) [0x00000] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.OwinResponse.Set[T] (System.String key, T value) [0x00006] in <0850b9daadb8416ca216d3d37f3983d1>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.OwinResponse.set_StatusCode (System.Int32 value) [0x00000] in <0850b9daadb8416ca216d3d37f3983d1>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.OwinResponse.Redirect (System.String location) [0x00000] in <0850b9daadb8416ca216d3d37f3983d1>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.InvokeReplyPathAsync () [0x002c9] in <dcea7978bc3a4441882e0efa5daced72>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationHandler.InvokeAsync () [0x00068] in <dcea7978bc3a4441882e0efa5daced72>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[TOptions].Invoke (Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context) [0x00109] in <1cc66b39b04f4b919683032a3a12cc4f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp (System.Func`2[T,TResult] entryPoint, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] environment, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult result) [0x0007e] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[TOptions].Invoke (Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context) [0x00183] in <1cc66b39b04f4b919683032a3a12cc4f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.AuthenticationMiddleware`1[TOptions].Invoke (Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext context) [0x00183] in <1cc66b39b04f4b919683032a3a12cc4f>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContextStage.RunApp (System.Func`2[T,TResult] entryPoint, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[TKey,TValue] environment, System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource`1[TResult] tcs, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult result) [0x0007e] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.DoFinalWork (Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult result) [0x0007d] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow () [0x00000] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x0001d] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x00006] in <90ddfcf805444e2e8c4aafed95112b04>:0 
  at System.Web.AsyncInvoker.<doAsyncCallback>b__8_0 (System.Object ores) [0x00007] in <d31574f4ab6745f49b1626160268508f>:0
```

I am using mono on linux, and I'm guessing it has something to do with the system web.config or routing. I've seen similar questions/answers but nothing I've read relates to this exact error. Is there a module I need to unregister or some other option that could be causing this?

Comment: Did you send a request and get a response?  Check with sniffer wireshark or fiddler.  I suspect you sent one request and failing 2nd.  Each request requires new request and cannot using previous request.  Not sure!!!  It looks like you are using a 3rd party dll and the dll may be doing the same as your code causing duplicate or you are trying to use request.

Comment: what version of mono are you using? what distribution of linux? what version of that distribution? how did you install mono in your distribution?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383169/server-cannot-set-status-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-iis7-5 . What happens is that you can't set the response code if the output is unbuffered and data flowed out (as the response code is generally the first line sent to the client).